# How to get check data from file in bash/Linux?

Tags: bash

I have data in a file in the form of

```
SID|SNAME|MARKS
1|a|90
2|b|56
```

and I want my answer to be

```
a A
b B
```

who have scored more than or equal to 90 grade will be A,
who have scored between 40 to 60 grade will be B,
else grade will be C.

What will be the bash command(s) for getting the respective result?

Comment: I have tried everything that I know after that I have posted the question.

Comment: What have you tried? Show your code so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. I can elaborate with more comments if anything is unclear.

```sh
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n' # change IFS word splitter to \n because names might have spaces

sed 1d grade.txt | while read line; do # skip first line while reading grade.txt
    array=( $(tr '|' '\n' <<< $line) ) # split line into array

    name="${array[1]}" # quotes because names could have spaces
    mark=${array[2]}
    if (( mark >= 90 )); then
        grade=A
    elif (( mark > 40 && mark < 60 )); then
        grade=B
    else
        grade=C
    fi

    echo "$name $grade"
done

IFS=$SAVEIFS # restore IFS
```

Sample `grade.txt` input:

```
SID|SNAME|MARKS
1|Jane Doe|90
2|Foo Bar|56
```

Sample output:

```
Jane Doe A
Foo Bar B
```